# Vagrant: Multiple boxes of laravel/homestead. How to remove the old one via macOS command line?

Tags: laravel, macos, vagrant, homestead

Typing `vagrant box list` gives:

```
$ vagrant box list
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 6.3.0)
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 8.0.1)
```

Indeed the `8.0.1` is the one I upgraded a minute ago.

[image]

How can I entirely (and safely) remove the old one (6.3.0) to free the disk space?

[According to the documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#box-remove), the `vagrant box remove NAME` requires box name. Since both boxes are named the same, which CLI command will help me remove the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#box-version-value-1) you can use the `box-version` option to remove only certain versions:

```
vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --box-version=6.3.0
```

Just tested it myself and it worked:

[image]